# Selenium + sikuli Error- *No ClassDefFoundError: org/sikuli/script/Screen* in command prompt

Tags: selenium, sikuli

When I'm running Selenium+ sikuli project in Command prompt getting error as

> *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sikuli/script/Screen and java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sikuli.script.Screen*

```
Screen screen = new Screen();
Pattern fileUpload = new Pattern("fileUpload(1).PNG");
screen.click(fileUpload);
```

If any best tool than sikuli for GUI testing integrates with selenium, please Suggest.

Comment: Are you running this java code from IDE or command line?

Comment: *java eclipse* - no issues in Java getting output. But when I'm trying to run through Command prompt getting above issue.

Comment: Have you added the Sikuli API dependency to your project. if Yes, Then remove and add it again and restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the above from command line, you probably did not define the classpath correctly and the classes you are referring to were not found. Make sure you include all related paths where your classes exist:

```
$ javac –classpath C:\dependency\framework.jar MyApp.Java
$ java –classpath C:\dependency\framework.jar MyApp
```